# Is it possible to write a replacement for 'require_once' etc. in PHP?

Tags: php

I have just written and tested my first non-hobby WordPress plugin, under Xampp on Windows 7, with PHP 5.3.8, and deployed it to my blog host, which is also a Windows environment, but I don't know what.

My first big surprise was nothing I could do to get relative paths working in `require_once`, so I have switched a few calls to use absolute paths - URL file access is  disabled - but I want to wedge in an layer of abstraction here.

How could I wrap `require_once` to concentrate the decision on how to build the path into one location, e.g. a `my_require_once` that builds a path, then injects source from that path into the interpretation queue or whatever. Should I even be contemplating this?

I am aware that I can encapsulate the path determination into a function and use that function in the path parameter to `require`, but I would like to be able to 'undermine' existing `require` calls.

Comment: Should I even be contemplating this? No!

Comment: Don't bother. PHP already does all the path normalization internally, so regardless of HOW you provide a path to any one file, PHP will (within reason) not re-include it.

Comment: Are you sure it's a Windows environment?  If it's not, there's a chance files and folders and case-sensitive, so that's something to consider.

Comment: You could write function that biuld a path for inclusion but still you should use `include()` / `require()` after you build path.

Comment: @piotrekkr, I forgot to add, I am aware of this, but I want to avoid the risk of updating all the `require` statements in my existing code.

Comment: Please make yourself comfortable with [Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to manipulate the relative paths in some more sophisticated way than just trying to prepend a number of absolute ones, `set_include_path` should be everything you need. Don't forget to append existing path though:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $your_folders).PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
```

This has effect on all subsequent include/require/_once, but not any other file functions. You should also check that WordPress doesn't already do that, it might itself have a setting to set the path.

And answering to your question, no, it's not possible to override require_once. You can, however, use `spl_autoload_register` and avoid using require_once at all.

Answer (score 2):

Define a base URL in a configuration file and append the relative path in the require_once statement:

```
require_once(BASE_URI . '/myfolder/myfile.php');
```